# How to configure the PhpStorm on Mac OS X to run in browser

Tags: phpstorm

I have tried to configure the PhpStorm(for Mac) to run a php file in browser, but the browser always show the "**Not Found**
The requested URL /PhpstormProjects/test_01/index.php was not found on this server."

What am I doing wrong??
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

do you use PHP Web Application run configuration to run your php? What does your Start URL look like? It should be smth like `'/PhpstormProjects/test_01/index.php'` - a path relative to the folder that is mapped to the root folder of the server host.

Comment: I added a PHP Web Applcation in the 'Run/Debug Configurations' dialog box, the 'Start URL' is http://localhost/

Comment: I followed some Tutorials I found on the Internet, they made a alias of the real PhpStormProjects folder, and move it to the /Library/WebServer/Documents/ , Is it right? @lena

Comment: Can you clarify what tutorials are meant?

Comment: just 'http://localhost' is not a correct URL. You need to specify server host, port and path mappings (in case if you server is not local and project files are not in the server doc root) in server settings, choose this server for your PHP Web Application run configuration, and specify a path to your local php file relative to the folder that is mapped to the root folder of the server host.